# PHP/MYSql PDO Select with variable

Tags: php, mysql

**Edit:** Ok, so while this does work great for `$ID` when I set it equal to `28`, it is not working for instance below if I was trying to get the `$name = $TableRows['name'];` variable. I know I could select it, but other variables require this.

```
$ID = 28; 
$name = $TableRows['name']; 

try { ini_set('display_errors', true); 
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare(" SELECT ? AS name FROM TABLE1 e WHERE id = ?"); 
$stmt->execute(array($name, $ID));
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v;
}
}
```

I'm in the process of transitioning from MySQLi to PDO. My problem is I'd like to modify one of the values in my `SELECT` query, similar to how I set my WHERE value of `ID` to `$ID = 28`. Does anyone know how instead of just outputting `millisecondstime` from the SELECT query, I could change it to output `$minutes $secondsrounded $millisecondsround` instead? This is the idea that I am going for:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, $minutes, $secondsrounded, $millisecondsround FROM TABLE1 e
```

This is my entire query:

```
<?php
echo "<center><div style='max-width: 1100px'><table id ='myTable' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <thead>
    ";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Time</th></tr></thead>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$name = $TableRows['name'];

$milliseconds = $TableRows['millisecondstime'];

$time = $milliseconds / 1000;
$days = floor($time / (24*60*60));
$hours = floor(($time - ($days*24*60*60)) / (60*60));
$minutes = floor(($time - ($days*24*60*60)-($hours*60*60)) / 60);
$seconds = ($time - ($days*24*60*60) - ($hours*60*60) - ($minutes*60)) % 60;

$str_length = 3;
$millisecondsround = substr("000{$milliseconds}", -$str_length);
$secondsrounded = str_pad($seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$ID = 28;   

try {
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, millisecondstime FROM TABLE1 e 
        WHERE ID = ?
        ORDER BY millisecondstime ASC
        "); 

    $stmt->execute(array($ID));
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: That isn't a very good db design having minutes, seconds and miliiseconds as column names. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: They're not the column names. They are the variables I'm setting and manipulating from the **millisecondstime** value.

Comment: Ok. Well Barmar seems to have a solution for you; give that a whirl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use placeholders in the `SELECT` list, and they'll be replaced with the values from the parameter array.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT name, ? AS minutes, ? AS secondsrounded, ? AS millisecondsround 
    FROM TABLE1 e 
    WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($minutes, $secondsrounded, $millisecondsround, $ID));
```

Comment: Can you really do that?

Comment: Yes. Placeholders can be used wherever expressions are allowed. You can write `SELECT 1 AS minutes FROM ...`

Comment: heh, interesting.

Comment: I actually have code that does something like this.

Comment: What I like about this place is that one never ceases to learn.

Comment: And while I teach 99% of the time, every now and then I learn something new.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! :)

Comment: Ok, so while this does work great for **ID** when I set it equal to **28**, it is not working for instance below if I was trying to get the **$name = $TableRows['name'];** variable. I know I could select it, but other variables require that I do it this way.

I edited my original question.

Comment: The question doesn't show how you set `$TableRows`.

Comment: My entire code should be up there, but it's used as an array with a class for organizing the values into an array and html table: class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

Comment: Also in the for each statement: $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;

Comment: Why doesn't it work for `$name`? It's not clear why you would write a query that only selects a variable and doesn't select anything from the database.

Comment: It does work for **$name** normally in the SELECT statement if I said **SELECT name...** since the **TableRows** array is also getting the data from **$stmt**. However, it just returns blank data if I used a placeholder **?** and said **SELECT ? as name...** and then set the **$name** variable to  **$name = $TableRows['name'];**. The reason I had to include **$TableRows** is because this variable sorts the data into an HTML table with **$k=>$v** as a **foreach** statement. I'm using this as an example since there will be other variables I can't just output from SELECT and I have to modify them

Comment: I still don't understand where `$TableRows` comes from. Is it an input parameter or the result of the query? None of your code shows how it's being set.

Comment: If it's the result of the query, then it doesn't make sense to use `$name` in the query itself, that's backwards.

Comment: Input parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, millisecondstime FROM TABLE1 e
WHERE ID = :ID
ORDER BY millisecondstime ASC
"); 

   $stmt->execute(array('ID' => $ID));
```

Comment: It doesn't come from the table, it's a variable he set earlier in the script.

Comment: Thanks, but if I add the other variables to the array, I'll get:  **Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.** I still need to set **millisecondstime** equal to those three variables. 

`$stmt->execute(array('ID' => $ID, 'millisecondstime' => $minutes $secondsrounded $millisecondsround));`